# Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal command to find all specific file types

Tags: ubuntu

What is the command in the Terminal for find all files of a specific file type? E.g., all jpegs.

I'm looking for a global search similarly to that on Windows/MacOSX where you can find all files with a specific type.

What is the equivalent for this on the Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: The question isn't really well-defined.  Convention dictates that file names with file extensions `*.jpg`, `*.JPEG`, etc should be JPEG files, but there is nothing to actually enforce this on a U*x-like system.  In fact, for a long time, [one of the Ubuntu wallpaper files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/+bug/296538) was incorrectly named `*.png` even though it was a JPEG file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the **"find"** with option **-name** like this e.g. to find all files with extension "*.txt":

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The **find** command is your solution.

> find >directory path< -name *.>extension<

(Please ignore the > < signs.. Had to type them this way)

Will list all files in the directory path with the specified extension.

You can search for any string, not just *.XXXXXX

Comment: Is there a global search version of this without having to put in the directory path? `*.*` perhaps? So for your suggestion it would be `find /var/ name *.jpg` ?

Comment: Put "*.extension" in quotes to prevent the shell from expanding the "\*"

Comment: @purpledot - you can just give the directory path as / i.e. root directory. That way it will search globally through the entire filesystem. (This could be incredibly slow though :P )